# JSON encode Data Getinto foreach

Tags: php, json, encode, jsonencoder

how to get foreach the belos json_encode data.. I am looking to get this data into foreach and then save into mysql.

```
[
{
"trends":[
{
name:"#PondyWelcomesTHALAPATHY",
url:"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23PondyWelcomesTHALAPATHY",
promoted_content:null,
query:"%23PondyWelcomesTHALAPATHY",
tweet_volume:100685
},
{
name:"#SaamySquareFromSep21",
url:"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23SaamySquareFromSep21",
promoted_content:null,
query:"%23SaamySquareFromSep21",
tweet_volume:null
},
],
"as_of":"2018-09-14T14:19:50Z",
"created_at":"2018-09-14T14:13:53Z",
"locations":[
{
name:"Mumbai",
woeid:2295411
}
]
}
]
```

Comment: I have tried few ways, but did not success.. so any one provide some pice of php code for this to get the name, url into foreach loop.

Comment: I found the solution for this json data..
$arr = array_values( $object );

$count=sizeof($arr[0]->trends);

echo $count;
echo "</br>";

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
   echo "</br>";
   echo $arr[0]->trends[$i]->name;
    }